# Issue with x-editable bootstrap 2 typeahead

Tags: x-editable

Can somebody help identify the issue with this -

http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/8823/

I am trying to implement a x-editable (bootstrap 2) typeahead functionality.

The jsfiddle above has two tests. 
1) is local source emulation 
2) is ajax emulation (remote data source)

I have taken the exact same examples from x-editable documentation, however something is wrong in the js resources that I am not able to identify. Typeahead is not working as expected.

AS per my understanding all it needs is bootstrap-editable.js for bootstrap 2 and bootstrap.js (2.3.2 which has typeahead plugin) to get this working.

jsfiddle code as per the guidelines :

HTML

```
<div>
    <p>Test 1 - local source emulation</p>
<a href="#" id="state" data-type="typeahead" data-pk="1" data-placement="right" data-title="Start typing State.." class="editable editable-click" style="display: inline;">Arizona</a>

</div>
<p/>
<div>
    <p>Test 2 - remote data source emulation/ ajax</p> <a href="#" id="state2" data-type="typeahead" data-pk="1" data-placement="right" data-title="Start typing State.." class="editable editable-click" style="display: inline;">California</a>

</div>
```

JS

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

//Test #1 local source emulation
$(function () {
    $('#state').editable({
        source: ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Dakota", "North Carolina", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"]
    });
});

//Test #2 ajax emulation for the next step (remote data source)
$(function () {
    $('#state2').editable({
        value: 'Alabama',
        source: function (query, process) {
            return $.post('/typeahead', {
                query: query
            }, function (data) {
                return process(data);
            });
        }
    });
});


$.mockjax({
    url: '/typeahead',
    responseTime: 400,
    response: function (settings) {
        this.responseText = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Dakota", "North Carolina", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used their example before ([HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/62/)) and it seems to work fine. Is [(your updated example)](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/8894/) what you are trying to achieve or I missed something?

You canh also set all options in JS, which is much cleaner, like so:

```
$('#state2').editable({
    type: 'text',
    url: '/typeahead',
    pk: 1,
    title: 'Enter username',
    ajaxOptions: {
        dataType: 'json'
    },
    success: function (response, newValue) {
        //code here
    }
});
```

Comment: typeahead functionality is not working, i dont see any suggestions after typing in that input text box. Update - I was able to get this working with bootstrap 3.2.0, jquery-1.9.1, typeahead.js-0.11.1 . thanks for your help.